# Limit of $\frac{n!}{(n + 1)! + n^2}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate the limit as $n \to \infty$ of: $a_n:=\frac{n!}{(n + 1)! + n^2}$

I tried using the Ratio Test but got $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=1$, which is inconclusive. Any help on how to evaluate this limit would be appreciated.

Comment: $$0<a_n\leqslant\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}\to0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\forall n>0 \;\;a_n<\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}$$

$$\implies 0<a_n<\frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
a_n:=\frac{n!}{(n + 1)! + n^2}=\frac{1}{n+1+ \frac{n}{(n-1)!}}.
$$